# DIV height problem (wrong height) in JQuery

Tags: jquery

in some pages, I want to make two Divs **the same height** by JQuery. one div is sidebar and another is the content part. but there is a problem in my codes, I think. when there are some images in the page, the height will be wrong because of loading slowly and one div will be shorter than another.

my HTML codes:

```
<section>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</section>
```

my JQuery codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".sidebar").height($(".content").height());

});
```

I even use the following codes but nothing happens:

```
jQuery( window ).load(function($) {

    $(".sidebar").height($(".content").height());

});
```

## Answer:

as **@Roko C. Buljan** told me, I solved this by CSS. Thanks

Comment: just out of curiosity... is sidebar fixed while content scrolls, or?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I tried CSS but it can not help me. Because I do not want sidebar to be longer than content. I want to know the content height and if sidebar is longer than that, can be scrolled and if it is shorter than content, be the same height.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan how is it? Would you write the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `display: flex`, and no more worries about loading assets, cached assets, page load listeners etc.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #0bf;
}

.content {
  background: #f0b;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="page">       <!-- add a class -->
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">
     <p>content and image...</p>
     <img src="//placehold.it/300x1000/fb0">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i do not want sidebar be longer than content and when it happans, it can scroll. but by CSS we can not control that. am I right?

Comment: @Sh.Dehnavi of cource you can do that using CSS. inside the sidebar place an absolute `div` with height and width at 100%. Set the `overflow: auto;` and you're done. In such case, if the sidebar content is longer than content's, it'll have it's own scrollbar. But it does makes no sense in doing it: https://jsfiddle.net/k3s5oqz7/ since it's totally weird.

Comment: my friend, you saved me really. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need but still I think CSS is a better solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let contentHeight = $('.content').height();

  $('.sidebar').height(contentHeight);
});
```

Comment: I tried CSS but it can not help me. Because I do not want sidebar to be longer than content. I want to know the content height and if sidebar is longer than that, can be scrolled and if it is shorter than content, be the same height

Comment: Is your code exactll like mine? Did you pay attention to this: "when there are some images in the page, the height will be wrong because of loading slowly and one div will be shorter than another".

Comment: Well, how you think to set sidebar height to be as content if you don't know content height? CSS display: flex; is the best solution and if your page is loading slowly then you have much bigger problems than sidebar height.

Comment: I explain that in this new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139928/adjust-a-divs-height-based-on-another-div-by-css/57140104?noredirect=1#comment100796209_57140104) and please see my page to find out my mean (https://end-eng.com/landing-grammar/)