# adjust a div's height based on another div by CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I have two DIVs (one is a sidebar and the other one is a content part) that I need to have the same height but I have a problem. The sidebar includes some `li`s. I want the height of the sidebar to be the same as the content part but when I use `flex`, the height of the sidebar can be longer than the content part (because both parts are dynamic). So **I need the sidebar to be scrolled when the height is longer than the content part**.

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><li>
            <li><li>
            <li><li>
            <li><li>
            <li><li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</section>
```

My CSS code:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.sidebar,.content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

I even used JQuery but we see the **wrong height** because images are being loaded slowly in the content part.

My JQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".sidebar").height($(".content").height());

});
```

I even used the following code but nothing happens:

```
jQuery( window ).load(function($) {

    $(".sidebar").height($(".content").height());

});
```

I do not want to use `position:absolute` because... You can see my page in this link: https://end-eng.com/landing-grammar/

Comment: have you tried `$('img').load()` instead of `$(window).load()`?

Comment: @Frish No my friend. I solved it by CSS.

Comment: Cool, what did you end up with?

Comment: @Frish My answer is below, my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I told above, I wanted sidebar to be scrolled when the sidebar is longer than content. so I solved it by pure CSS:
my new HTML code:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebardiv">
            <ul>
                <li><li>
                <li><li>
                <li><li>
                <li><li>
                <li><li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</section>
```

my new CSS code:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.sidebar , .content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.sidebardiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is very close! If you instead set the flex properties on the parent, you will have two equal-height divs. I added some colours to illustrate:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.sidebar {
    background: red;
}

.content {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><li>
            <li><li>
            <li><li>
            <li><li>
            <li><li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">hello content</div>
</section>
```

Here's some reading on the `flex` shorthand you're using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

If you need the sidebar to be scrolled when the height is longer than the content, then you can use jQuery to match the elements' heights on a `resize` event (to keep it consistent) like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = '.content';
  var b = '.sidebar'
  matchHeight(a, b); // set at beginning
  $(window).resize(function() {
    matchHeight(a, b); // reset on window resize
  })
});

// set height of one element to another
// target: height to match
// el: element to match to target height
function matchHeight(target, el) {
  var targetHeight = $(target).height();
  $(el).css('height', targetHeight);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.sub-container {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <li>
          <li>
            <li>
              <li>
                <li>
                  <li>
                    <li>
                      <li>
                        <li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="content">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
      one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: did you read my question right? I need sidebar to be scrolled when the height is longer than content part

Comment: Must have glossed over that part! I've added a jQuery solution, however it's not the prettiest thing. You may want to handle the condition where, if sidebar height < content height, the CSS overflow property changes to get rid of the now-inactive sidebar.

Comment: I know what you mean but the problem is loading images in content part that make us to have a wrong height when we use `$(document).ready` and when I use `jQuery( window ).load(` to get height, nothing happen!!!

Comment: Hmmm, after reading the jQuery doc page https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ I'm inclined to think you should bind the load event handler to the `img` elements, not the `document` as you've shown in your initial question. Try that and let me know what happens!

Comment: I am really confused now, would you tell your idea in your answer by code? thanks

Comment: The [jQuery documentation page for .load()](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) tells it better than I could -- and there are code examples!

Comment: Did you see my question completely? I tried it but nothing happens!!! to get the height after window loading

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code it's very simple way to achieve sidebar and main content using flexbox; [Codepen example goes here](https://codepen.io/rajeshkumarsah/pen/yrEZMX)

Html goes here...

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
           <li>list item</li>
           <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">content goes here...</div>
</section>
```

css goes here

```
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.sidebar{
  height:100vh;
  width:200px;
  background:#ccc;
  overflow:auto; // overflow:auto; will scroll when your content reach 100vh height
}
```

Comment: I don not want to use posotion:absolute beacuse... you can see my page in this link: https://end-eng.com/landing-grammar/

Comment: I did't use position, you can achieve this using flexbox

Comment: I need the sidebar to be scrolled when the height is longer than the content part.

Comment: Yea you can check the codepen example @Sh.Dehnavi as per your requirement I have fixed your problem buddy

Comment: you can add more list item to see scroll problem

Comment: Yea your code is correct but how can I do on my page (https://end-eng.com/landing-grammar/) I think these two are different.

Comment: your html is same like mine, you can replace your css with mine one